# What's the scope of a method in Go?

Tags: go, methods, scope

From the spec ('Declarations and scope'):

> The scope of an identifier denoting a constant, type, variable, or function (but not method) declared at top level (outside any function) is the package block.

I guess it implies that the scope of an identifier denoting a method not a package block.

Then what is it? I did not manage to find any info in the spec.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Method names do not have a scope. They must always be qualified by a value or type.

Answer (score 3):

> [The Go Programming Language Specification](https://golang.org/ref/spec)
>
> [Method declarations](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Method_declarations)
>
> A method is a function with a receiver. A method declaration binds an
>   identifier, the method name, to a method, and associates the method
>   with the receiver's base type.
>
> The receiver is specified via an extra parameter section preceding the
>   method name. That parameter section must declare a single non-variadic
>   parameter, the receiver. Its type must be of the form T or *T
>   (possibly using parentheses) where T is a type name. The type denoted
>   by T is called the receiver base type; it must not be a pointer or
>   interface type and it must be defined in the same package as the
>   method. The method is said to be bound to the base type and the method
>   name is visible only within selectors for type T or *T.

---

> The method is said to be bound to the base type and the method name is
>   visible only within selectors for type T or *T.